# How to Fix [SQL0811] Result of SELECT more than one row

Tags: sql, database, db2

Hi guys I get a problem about SQL query on DB2, can you help me?
 This is my code. [SQL0811] Result of SELECT more than one row .

```
SELECT
        VIEW_FCLT_REGISTER.BUSINESS_GROUP_NAME AS FCLT_REGISTER_BUSINESS_GROUP_NAME,
        VIEW_FCLT_REGISTER.ID_FACILITY_NO      AS ID_FACILITY_NO,
        CASE VIEW_FCLT_REGISTER."FCLT_STATUS"
            WHEN 'M'
            THEN 'Amendment'
            WHEN 'A'
            THEN 'Approved'
            WHEN 'F'
            THEN 'Closed'
            WHEN 'C'
            THEN 'Created'
            WHEN 'Y'
            THEN 'Delete'
            WHEN 'E'
            THEN 'Expired'
            WHEN 'I'
            THEN 'Incompleted'
            WHEN 'N'
            THEN 'New Facility'
            WHEN 'O'
            THEN 'Operational'
            WHEN 'P'
            THEN 'Pending'
            WHEN 'L'
            THEN 'Ready For Closing'
            WHEN 'D'
            THEN 'Ready For Disburse'
            WHEN 'R'
            THEN 'Recovery'
            WHEN 'Z'
            THEN 'Reject At Approval'
            WHEN 'U'
            THEN 'Restructure'
            WHEN 'V'
            THEN 'Reviewed'
            WHEN 'T'
            THEN 'Terminated'
            WHEN 'W'
            THEN 'Waiting For Disburse'
        END                                           AS FCLT_REGISTER_STATUS,
        VIEW_FCLT_REGISTER.CLOSE_DATE                                              AS FCLT_CLOSING_DATE,
        CONCAT (VIEW_FCLT_REGISTER.NAME , CONCAT (', ', VIEW_FCLT_REGISTER.COMPANY_TYPE)) AS
                               LESSEE_NAME,
        OBJECT_LEASE."NAME"               AS ASSET_DESCRIPTION,
        VIEW_OBJECT_LAD."OWNER_NAME"      AS VIEW_OBJECT_LAD_OWNER_NAME,
        VIEW_OBJECT_LAD."ADDRESS"         AS VIEW_OBJECT_LAD_ADDRESS,
        PRM_CITY.DESCRIPTION              AS CITY,
        VIEW_OBJECT_LAD."DOCUMENT_STATUS" AS VIEW_OBJECT_LAD_DOCUMENT_STATUS,
        (
            SELECT
                FCLT_OBJECT_LEASE_INFO."INFORMATION" AS FCLT_OBJECT_LEASE_INFO_FID_CODE
            FROM
                "BTMU"."FCLT_OBJECT_LEASE_INFO" FCLT_OBJECT_LEASE_INFO
            INNER JOIN
                "BTMU"."PRM_GENERIC" PRM_GENERIC
            ON
                FCLT_OBJECT_LEASE_INFO."FID_CODE" = PRM_GENERIC."ID_GENERIC"
            WHERE
                PRM_GENERIC."DESCRIPTION" = 'Chasis No'
            AND FCLT_OBJECT_LEASE_INFO.FID_OBJECT_LEASE = VIEW_OBJECT_LAD.FID_OBJECT_LEASE) AS
        CHASIS_NO,
        (
            SELECT
                FCLT_OBJECT_LEASE_INFO."INFORMATION" AS FCLT_OBJECT_LEASE_INFO_FID_CODE
            FROM
                "BTMU"."FCLT_OBJECT_LEASE_INFO" FCLT_OBJECT_LEASE_INFO
            INNER JOIN
                "BTMU"."PRM_GENERIC" PRM_GENERIC
            ON
                FCLT_OBJECT_LEASE_INFO."FID_CODE" = PRM_GENERIC."ID_GENERIC"
            WHERE
                PRM_GENERIC."DESCRIPTION" = 'Engine No'
            AND FCLT_OBJECT_LEASE_INFO.FID_OBJECT_LEASE = VIEW_OBJECT_LAD.FID_OBJECT_LEASE) AS
        ENGINE_NO,
        (
            SELECT
                FCLT_OBJECT_LEASE_INFO."INFORMATION" AS FCLT_OBJECT_LEASE_INFO_FID_CODE
            FROM
                "BTMU"."FCLT_OBJECT_LEASE_INFO" FCLT_OBJECT_LEASE_INFO
            INNER JOIN
                "BTMU"."PRM_GENERIC" PRM_GENERIC
            ON
                FCLT_OBJECT_LEASE_INFO."FID_CODE" = PRM_GENERIC."ID_GENERIC"
            WHERE
                PRM_GENERIC."DESCRIPTION" = 'Police No'
            AND FCLT_OBJECT_LEASE_INFO.FID_OBJECT_LEASE = VIEW_OBJECT_LAD.FID_OBJECT_LEASE) AS
        POLICE_NO,
        (
            SELECT
                FCLT_OBJECT_LEASE_INFO."INFORMATION" AS FCLT_OBJECT_LEASE_INFO_FID_CODE
            FROM
                "BTMU"."FCLT_OBJECT_LEASE_INFO" FCLT_OBJECT_LEASE_INFO
            INNER JOIN
                "BTMU"."PRM_GENERIC" PRM_GENERIC
            ON
                FCLT_OBJECT_LEASE_INFO."FID_CODE" = PRM_GENERIC."ID_GENERIC"
            WHERE
                PRM_GENERIC."DESCRIPTION" = 'Serial Number'
            AND FCLT_OBJECT_LEASE_INFO.FID_OBJECT_LEASE = VIEW_OBJECT_LAD.FID_OBJECT_LEASE) AS
                                           SERIAL_NO,
        VIEW_OBJECT_LAD."RECEIVED_DATE" AS VIEW_OBJECT_LAD_RECEIVED_DATE,
        FA_SUPPLIER_ASSET."NAME"        AS FA_SUPPLIER_ASSET_NAME
    FROM
        BTMU.VIEW_OBJECT_LAD VIEW_OBJECT_LAD
    INNER JOIN
        BTMU.PRM_GENERIC PRM_GENERIC
    ON
        PRM_GENERIC.ID_GENERIC = VIEW_OBJECT_LAD.FID_CODE
    INNER JOIN
        BTMU.FCLT_OBJECT_LEASE OBJECT_LEASE
    ON
        OBJECT_LEASE.ID_OBJECT_LEASE = VIEW_OBJECT_LAD.FID_OBJECT_LEASE
    INNER JOIN
        BTMU.VIEW_FCLT_REGISTER VIEW_FCLT_REGISTER
    ON
        VIEW_FCLT_REGISTER.ID_FACILITY_NO = OBJECT_LEASE.FID_FACILITY_NO
    INNER JOIN
        BTMU.FA_SUPPLIER_ASSET FA_SUPPLIER_ASSET
    ON
        OBJECT_LEASE."FID_SUPPLIER_ASSET" = FA_SUPPLIER_ASSET."ID_SUPPLIER_ASSET"
    INNER JOIN
        BTMU.PRM_GENERIC PRM_CITY
    ON
        OBJECT_LEASE."FID_CITY" = PRM_CITY."ID_GENERIC"
    WHERE
        VIEW_FCLT_REGISTER."STATUS" = 'A'
    AND UPPER(PRM_GENERIC.DESCRIPTION) LIKE UPPER('BPKB')
    AND VIEW_OBJECT_LAD.STATUS = 'A'
    AND VIEW_OBJECT_LAD.DOCUMENT_STATUS = 'A'
```

Comment: i can't even look at the logs, its just a big mess take a look on the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), on the **asking** section

Answer (score 0):

Any of the subqueries(selects inside selects) might be returning more than one row depending on the join.

Add top 1 for all the select queries

Comment: `TOP 1` isn't valid in DB2, but that's potentially what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Use FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
Ex :
Select column1, column2, ...
From table
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY